# Best tool to determine code Cyclomatic complexity

Tags: c#, cyclomatic-complexity

Can people suggest the best tool to determine the cyclic complexity with in a C# winforms code base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) has a huge number of code analysis and query tools including [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#CC) per type and method estimation.

Comment: +1 for NDepend. Has a learning curve but you get a in depth look at your code.

Answer (score 33):

In Visual Studio I just go to Analyze/Calculate Code Metrics and I get cyclomatic complexity.

#### 3rd party edit

- Visual Studio 2015 community edition has it as well

Comment: I don't believe it is in VS 2005 although I am not certain.

Comment: It's not in VS 2005 or 2008 Pro -- are you perhaps using Team System or a similar top-end version?

Comment: It is in VS 2010 Ultimate，just in case someone ran into this old question like me :)

Comment: It's in VS 2012 Professional, to update the comments.

Comment: But the Complexity Visual studio 2012 gives is IL complexity and not actual code complexity

Comment: Just checked VS 2015 Enterprise and it is there.

Comment: It's in VS 2017 Community, but it doesn't calculate for .NET Core / .NET Standard projects, nor Web projects. And it seems [MS won't change it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28145/calculate-code-metrics-doesnt-work-for-net-standar.html) (at least not soon).

Answer (score 8):

We are using [SourceMonitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html). It's free, very easy to use and easy to integrate with a CI server.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress's [Refactor Pro](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) does that.  It has a free trial, so you may want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plugin for Red Gate's .NET Reflector called [CodeMetrics](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=CodeMetrics) that does this.